# visual studio 2012 allegro 5 x64 linker

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, allegro5

I've the same problem as [Can't build Allegro 5 solution in MSVC 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490085/cant-build-allegro-5-solution-in-msvc-2012) but my project is x64 and I have Win8 x64 professional. And when I'm turn to Win32 everytging is ok. But when turn to x64 I have this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test_allegro, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_install_system referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_rest referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_map_rgb referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_create_display referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_destroy_display referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_flip_display referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol al_clear_to_color referenced in function main
1>D:\Biblioteki\Dropbox\studia\przedmioty\sem_3\aisdi\laboratorium\test_allegro\x64\Debug\test_allegro.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas? My project have to be x64...

Comment: Did you build Allegro yourself? Allegro binaries are 32-bit. Build and link to 64-bit versions.

Comment: I build it and now everything works. Thanks!